# Filling the entries of a matrix

Tags: combinatorics, matrices

> Let $a_n$ be the number of ways to fill the entries of a $n\times 2$ matrix with the integers $1, \cdots, 2n$ such that the entries are increasing from left to right in each row of $2$ and from up to down in each column, is the $n$th Catalan number.

---

Observe that $a_0 = a_1 = 1.$ It suffices to show that $a_n = a_0a_{n-1} + \cdots + a_{n-1}a_0,$ since that is the recurrence relation of the Catalan numbers with the same initial conditions. Consider such an $n\times 2$ matrix. Pick a pair of entries $(a,b)$ along row $k+1$. Then there are $2k$ entries above it and $2n - 2 - 2k$ entries below it. $k$ may range from $0$ to $n-1.$ But how can I show that the number of ways to arrange the $2k$ entries above row $k+1$ equals $a_k$ and the number of ways to arrange the $2n-2-2k$ entries below row $k+1$ equals $a_{n-1}$? Do I need to define some sort of bijection?

> Edit: The definition of the $n$th Catalan number is, as one would expect, $\dfrac{1}{n+1}{2n\choose n}.$

Comment: Do you have any other definition for the Catalan numbers?

Comment: @Exodd see my edited post.

Comment: The common way to tackle these problems is give a bijection between such fillings of these $n \times 2$ matrices and another set counted by the Catalan numbers. A good such set for this example is the set of Super-Diagonal-Lattice paths or Dyck paths. Its easier to see that such paths satisfy the Catalan recurrence and therefore establishing a bijection with these matrix fillings will establish they are counted by the Catalan numbers.